# C# Spoof Host Name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hosts

**Background information**

I have users stored in a table, I have the concept of "companies" stored in a separate table, and then I have an intermediate table that links users to companies in a one(user) to many(companies) relationship. The situation that I have is that a user will register or log in from a domain specific to a company. The requirement is that I need to authorize users based on the domain they're coming from.

**What I'm Thinking**

I believe that you can get the domain name from [Request.Url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequestbase.url?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_HttpRequestBase_Url) and so I thought is that I would just get the name and do my authorization logic. The issue that I'm running into is that if I try to get the name via:

```
var hostName = Request.Url.DnsSafeHost
```

It always returns `localhost`. So to bypass this, I though that I could edit my HOSTS file to include this line:

```
localhost:12345 [domain I want to spoof].com
```

But even this still returns `localhost` so I am unsure if I'm even going about this correctly.

**Update**

As per a comment request, the operating system that I'm using is Windows 10.

Comment: In general network configuration questions are not on-topic on SO. SuperUser, ServerFault or one of Linux sites may be more appropriate (clarifying what OS you are using definitely needed for such question, especially since it's clearly not Windows which would be somewhat default for C# question)

Comment: There is no requirement that an outgoing IP address is properly registered. You  might be surprised what domains you get from DnsSafeHost.

Comment: I'm not sure `Request.Url` is what you want. According the documentation, it contains "_...information about the URL of the current request._". What exactly do you mean by the "domain they're coming from"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took quite a bit of searching, but I was ultimately able to resolve my issue. For future searches, here are some keywords that I should have used but didn't have enough knowledge beforehand to know what they were: IIS Express localhost alias.

The first thing to keep in mind is that everything that I did, **I had to do as an administrator**.

First, as per [Mark Mucha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59549030/1920035), I had to format my HOSTS file properly. In my case the alias that I wanted to use was `dev.myproject` which means I added the following line to my HOSTS file:

```
127.0.0.1 dev.myproject
```

I verified that this worked by bringing up a terminal (I personally use Git Bash) and submitted a ping request which responded with the following:

```
$ ping dev.myproject

Pinging dev.myproject [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
```

The next step was to configure an IIS Express alias. To do this, I went to my IIS Express configuration file, which is found at: `[solution directory]\.vs\config\applicationhost.config` (keep in mind that .vs is a hidden folder) and edited the file to include a new website binding. The new binding looks like the following:

```
<site name="myproject" id="2">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="[directory name removed]" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:52841:localhost" />
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:52841:dev.myproject" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

Once the website binding was setup I then modified my project's server properties by going to the project's properties (in the solution explorer, right-click on the project name, click on Properties at the very bottom, and then go to the Web tab). The project URL I left it as it was, but I checked the *Override Application URL* to be the alias that I wanted to use, in this case it look like:

```
http://dev.myproject:52841
```

The final step was to reserve the aliased URL for non-administrator users (because I generally don't run as an admin). In this case, I ran the following command from my terminal:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:52841/ user=\Everyone
```

Once the alias was setup in IIS Express, I was able to reach the aliased URL by launching the application (F5). This initially brought up `http://localhost:52841` but in a separate tab I navigated to `http://dev.myproject:52841` and it worked.

Now that everything was finished, the actual property that I needed to get was the following:

```
var host = Request.Url?.Host;
```

Answer (score 2):

From testing locally, you'll need to change the line in the hosts file to something like:
`127.0.0.1 foodbar.org`. Per the file itself, lines should be `<ip> <hostname>`.

Then, you'll have to navigate to http://foodbar.org when testing. I've done this in the past for testing TLS certs, and this worked for me. You may have to change your bindings in IIS.

Comment: Thank you, Mark. I updated the hosts file to use the IP Address and I've also added a new binding in IIS Express for my alias. It allows for me to ping the alias and it returns a reply from `127.0.0.1` but whenever I attempt to debug my application and navigate to the URL it returns a bad request.

Comment: Actually, take a look at my answer. I was able to resolve the issue by setting up a new binding in the IIS Express configuration for the project.